# How do I determine if a integer in a Java Intstream is of the form 3x+1?

Tags: java, java-stream

The question I was given is:

Find and print (one per line) those values of *a* that are of the form 3x+ 1 for some x. Each such value should be printed only once, in the position it first appears.

I have tried many variations of modulo to try and get the correct numbers but I can't seem to wrap my head around the problem.

This is the code I was given to start:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Example {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {
    int a[] =
      Arrays.stream(argv)
      .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
      .toArray();
  }
      // fill in here with expression starting Arrays.stream(a)

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: it seems homework question, you should be try yourself, and ask if you stuck somewhere. please write in detail what you tried and what issue you are facing rather than asking for answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `a` has the form `3x + 1` then `a - 1 = 3x` and thus you want to subtract one from each value and then test if the remainder with division would be zero. Then print the matches. Also, you could use `Integer::parseInt` and I would prefer the form `int[] a` over `int a[]` (the second form was preserved to be familiar to C and C++ developers) and (as pointed out by ernest_k in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445443/how-do-i-determine-if-a-integer-in-a-java-intstream-is-of-the-form-3x1/60445485?noredirect=1#comment106931574_60445485) use a `distinct()` to ensure uniqueness). Like,

```
int[] a = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
Arrays.stream(a).filter(x -> (x - 1) % 3 == 0)
        .distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I guess you need to call `distinct()` somewhere as there's a requirement to print the number only once. Can also be limited to just one stream pipeline (without the intermediate `int[]`)

Comment: @Naman `x -> x % 3 == 1` doesn’t work for negative numbers, so `x -> (x - 1) % 3 == 0` is preferable.

Comment: @Holger Yup, point taken. (not to assume integers would mostly be positive)